# How much does the projection map on a geodesic contract in negative curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Hadamard manifold with curvature $-b^2 \le K \le -1$. Let $c$ be a complete geodesic in $X$. For every $x \in X$, denote by $p_c(x)$ the projection of $x$ onto $c$. This projection map being $1$-Lipschitz, one has $d(p_c(x), p_c(y)) \le d(x, y)$ for every $x, y$.

Here's my question : if we know that $d(x, p_c(x)) \le r$ and $d(y, p_c(y)) \le r$, can we give an estimate about how fast $d(x, y) - d(p_c(x), p_c(y))$ goes to $0$ when $r$ goes to $0$ ? The triangle inequality yields
$$ d(x, y) - d(p_c(x), p_c(y)) \le 2 r$$
but I'd like to at least have a $(1+\varepsilon)$ instead of this $2$, possibly after assuming that $d(x, y)$ is large enough.

Comment: The largeness of $d(x,y)$ will certainly be necessary, as otherwise we can achieve $2r$ (at least in hyperbolic space) by choosing $x,y$ with the same projection on to and distance from $c$, but on opposite sides. Since you're interested in $r \to 0$ and have a sectional curvature condition, Jacobi fields seem like a natural choice to investigate this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "cutting" the two right angles at the projection points $p_c(x)$ and $p_c(y)$, and by applying the hyperbolic law of cosines in the resulting right triangles, I think I managed to prove that the defect is actually equivalent to $r^2$. This matches what happens in the Euclidean plane, and relies on the lower bound on the curvature (which is intuitive, since the lower the curvature can get, the closer the segment $[x, y]$ will get from $[p_c(x), p_c(y)]$).